# Action hook with wrapper html

Tags: hooks, actions

I want to add a space for a banner across the top of my WooCommerce Category pages, but i'm trying to figure out how to add some markup that will wrap the action.

In my archive-product.php I have the following code;

```
<?php 
    do_action('category_promo_header');
?>
```

Basically, if a Category has the 'category_promo_header' Action Hook Name set, I would like to output the content and wrapped in some additional markup such as;

```
<div class="row">...</div>
```

I want to do it this way so that the client doesn't have to remember to add the additional makeup every time. Do I need to do this in the functions.php or can i place some conditional in the archive-product.php?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the [`has_action()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_action) function.

```
add_action(
  'category_promo_header',
  function () {
    echo 'hi there';
  }
);

if (has_action('category_promo_header')) {
  echo '<div>';
    do_action('category_promo_header');
  echo '</div>';
}
```

Comment that `add_action` and you should see that nothing is printed at all.